# hyperlink to an external git repository in Sphinx PDF documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

External hyperlinks to a git repository in the form

```
.. _Git repo: git://github.com/migueldvb/repo.git
```

appear correctly in the HTML documentation but they do not show up in the PDF file. A warning appears when running `python setup.py sphinx_build -b latex` to generate the `LaTeX` file:

```
unusable reference target found git://github.com/...
```

How can an hyperlink to a git repository be included in the PDF documentation generated by Sphinx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
.. raw:: latex

    \href{git://github.com}{GitHub}

.. raw:: html

    <a href="git://github.com">GitHub</a>
```

Edit: I looked at the source code of sphinx and the warning message is produced in the file sphinx/writers/latex.py in the visit_reference method, which is defined as follows:

```
def visit_reference(self, node):
        uri = node.get('refuri', '')
        # ...
        elif uri.startswith('mailto:') or uri.startswith('http:') or \
                 uri.startswith('https:') or uri.startswith('ftp:'):
            self.body.append('\\href{%s}{' % self.encode_uri(uri))
        else:
            self.builder.warn('unusable reference target found: %s' % uri,
                              (self.curfilestack[-1], node.line))
            self.context.append('')
```

So the protocols are hardcoded and therefore I think there is no option or simple way without using raw data or changing the sphinx source to make "unknown" links work.

I added a line for the git protocol to the source code:

```
def visit_reference(self, node):
        uri = node.get('refuri', '')
        # ...
        elif uri.startswith('mailto:') or uri.startswith('http:') or \
                 uri.startswith('git:') or \
                 uri.startswith('https:') or uri.startswith('ftp:'):
            self.body.append('\\href{%s}{' % self.encode_uri(uri))
```

Now 'make latexpdf' and 'make html' were producing documents with a working git link with the following source:

```
Test Link
=========

This is a paragraph that contains `a link`_.

.. _a link: git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git
```

Comment: Thanks but I could not make this work for HTML and PDF at the same time.

Comment: Please see my new edit. I fixed it in the source code and I hope there are no side effects. :)